# JSON displaying incorrect output when entered correct login details

Tags: json, android-volley

I've tried directly passing the "admin" value for both username and password directly but still coming up with "result": 0 for the result key.
The code should output the below JSON if the following credentials are entered:

username = "admin"
password = "admin"

```
{
    "result": 1,
    "message": [
        "You got it!"
    ]
}
```

and the below JSON if wrong credentials

```
{
    "result": 0,
    "message": ["Username:","Password:d347fba9ba76bfea2da832198bea7a284cfc4452da06f5a8a33edef37d3cf1c2"]
}
```

Code for MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText etUsername, etPassword;
private Button btnLogin;
private com.android.volley.RequestQueue requestQueue;
private final String URL = "https://talentloop.net/app/android/main/login";
private StringRequest request;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    etUsername = findViewById(R.id.etUsername);
    etPassword = findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
    btnLogin = findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {

                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);

                        String toastString = "";
                        toastString = jsonObject.names().get(0).toString()+": "+jsonObject.getString("result");
                        toastString+="\n"+jsonObject.names().get(1).toString()+": "+jsonObject.getString("message");
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), toastString, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            })
                {
                    @Override
                    protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError
                    {
                        HashMap<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
                        hashMap.put("username",etUsername.getText().toString().trim());
                        hashMap.put("password",etPassword.getText().toString().trim());

                        return hashMap;
                    }
                };
            requestQueue.add(request);
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: `getParams()` method wont work with get request, see my answer below

Answer (score 0):

In case of **POST** method you can override the `getParams()`, but in get request this method is not even getting called

If you are using a **GET** request, you will need to concatenate the query params with the url and make the request.Try concatenating the params with your url, i.e change your request like this

```
request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, "https://talentloop.net/app/android/main/login?username="+etUsername.getText().toString()+"&password="+etPassword.getText().toString(), new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                try {

                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                    .
                    .
                    .
```